# IronPython strange method calling

Tags: list, methods, call, instance, ironpython

Why does calling a method like this in ironPython work?:

```
from System.Collections.Generic import List

class test:

    mem = None

    def __init__(self):
        # !No Instance created !!!
        self.mem = List[int]

    def doSomeThing(self):
        if self.mem.Contains((List[int](), 123):
            pass
```

I can't get the behaviour of IronPython in this case: `self.mem.Contains((List[int](), 123):`. Does any one has an explanation for this?

**EDIT**

Is `self.mem` only the type, and `Contains` will always return `False`? If this is true, it seems to be a nice feature :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true of normal Python classes as well:

```
class Foo(object):
  def bar(self):
    pass

f = Foo
f.bar(Foo())
```

It's the difference between bound (`Foo().bar`) and unbound (`Foo.bar`) methods. It's not so much a feature as a side effect of how methods are implemented in Python.

`Contains` is always false because it is working on an empty list, which contains nothing.

Comment: Yep, thank you, thats what i thought about: *Contains is always false because it is working on an empty list, which contains nothing.*

Comment: Just to clarify/avoid misunderstandings: It is working on the empty list provided in the call and not because an empty list is automatically created somewhere in the process. So `self.mem.Contains(List[int]([ 234, 456, 123, 345 ]), 123)` for example would return `True`.